# The deduction guide for std::array

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, stdarray, deduction-guide

In the C++ 17 and C++ 20 Working Drafts of the C++ Standard the deduction guide for the class template `std::array` is defined the following way

```
template<class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

As a result for example this declaration

```
std::array a = { 1ll, 2llu };
```

should be compiled and the deduced type of the variable `a` is `std::array<long long, 2>`.

However compilers use another deduction guide that checks that all initializers have the same type.

Is it a bug of compilers or was the deduction guide indeed changed in C++ 17 and C++20 Standards?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++17 has that requirement in the deduction guide.

> ```
> template<class T, class... U>
> array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `(is_­same_­v<T, U> && ...)` is true. Otherwise the program is ill-formed.

[`[array.cons#2]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array.cons#2)